# Get loop count inside a for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

This `for` loop iterates over all elements in a list:

```
for item in my_list:
    print item
```

Is there a way to know within the loop how many times I've been looping so far? For instance, I want to take a list and after I've processed ten elements I want to do something with them.

The alternatives I thought about would be something like:

```
count=0
for item in my_list:
    print item
    count +=1
    if count % 10 == 0:
        print 'did ten'
```

Or:

```
for count in range(0,len(my_list)):
    print my_list[count]
    if count % 10 == 0:
        print 'did ten'
```

Is there a better way (just like the `for item in my_list`) to get the number of iterations so far?

Comment: You might also be interested in the answers to iterating over a list in chunks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Answer (score 789, accepted):

The pythonic way is to use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for idx, item in enumerate(my_list):
```

Comment: Super duper , Just one magic line solving all problems

Comment: Phenomenal answer, I always come back to copy this line

Answer (score 124):

Agree with Nick. 
Here is more elaborated code.

```
#count=0
for idx, item in enumerate(list):
    print item
    #count +=1
    #if count % 10 == 0:
    if (idx+1) % 10 == 0:
        print 'did ten'
```

I have commented out the count variable in your code.

Comment: You could also use `enumerate`'s optional `start` parameter to start enumerating with 1 instead of 0, though then I'd use the OP's name `count` instead of `idx`.

Answer (score 4):

Using zip function we can get both element and index.

```
countries = ['Pakistan','India','China','Russia','USA']

for index, element in zip(range(0,countries),countries):

         print('Index : ',index)
         print(' Element : ', element,'\n')

output : Index : 0 Element : Pakistan ...
```

---

See also :

[Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0212/)