# Adding title to HTML table using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have the following code;

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Connect to the database.
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(
db='srt_test2',
user='root',
passwd='',
host='localhost')
c = conn.cursor()

# Print the contents of the database.
c.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
all_data = c.fetchall()
my_list = []
for item in all_data :
   my_list.append([item[1],item[4]])

my_page = """

<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>HTML Tables</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <table border="1">
{MY_TABLE}
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
"""
my_string = ""

for item in my_list :
   my_string += "      <tr>\n"
   for element in item :
       my_string += "         <td>" + str(element) + "</td>\n"
   my_string += "      </tr>\n"
# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

print(my_page.format(MY_TABLE=my_string))
```

When I print element 1 how can I get it to have a title of "username" and when I print element 4 how can I get it to have a title of "grade" ?
Thanks

Comment: Please fix your code indentation first

Comment: where do you want `"username"` and `"grade"` ? In table header or in the same `<td>` or in another column ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`th`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) element, like so:

```
 <table border="1">
 <tr><th>username</th><th>grade</th></tr>
 {MY_TABLE}
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. <strike>String  concatenation</strike>

2. <strike>[Template Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)</strike>
3. A fully featured template system like [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/)

I would also recommend to use some kind of web framework.

Edit:
I think I misunderstand your Question. #3 is still a valid option, and you can 
count your loop as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162271/get-loop-count-inside-a-python-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is just to add title for your table's columns, you can initialize your `my_string` variable like this:

```
my_string = '<tr><th>username</th><th>grade</th></tr>'
```