# Printing a list in Python and generating an ID column for each item (sequence of numbers)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Using Python I want to print the elements of a list using for loop and also I want to generate a number for each item in the list. Something like an ID column next to the column containing the list's items.

Example:

```
lst = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

for item in lst:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
One
Two
Three
```

What I would like to print:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get loop count inside a Python FOR loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162271/get-loop-count-inside-a-python-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method:

```
lst = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

for i, item in enumerate(lst, 1):
    print(i, item)
```

Output:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
```

A potential problem here is when the digits start becoming different lengths, like:

```
lst = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test']
```

Output:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
4 test
5 test
6 test
7 test
8 test
9 test
10 test
11 test
12 test
13 test
```

where the starting point of each word doesn't align anymore. That can be fixed with the [`str.ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) method:

```
lst = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test']

for i, item in enumerate(lst, 1):
    print(str(i).ljust(2), item)
```

Output:

```
1  One
2  Two
3  Three
4  test
5  test
6  test
7  test
8  test
9  test
10 test
11 test
12 test
13 test
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)

```
lst = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

for num,item in enumerate(lst,start=1):
    print(num,item)
```

Output:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
```