# How to print regular page number rather than a page number by a parameter?

Tags: python

Here's for loop I'm trying to work

```
for page in range(0, 27800, 20):
    print(f'page {page} =====')
```

If current page is '2', then this code may print out page number as '20'.
If current page is '5', code will print '80'.

I want my code to print actual page numbers such as 1,2,3,4,5,6....(not those parameter numbers)

So How I can do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162287/17851130

Comment: Could you explain why you added the third argument to the range?

Comment: @DrummerMann I think that's too hard to understand for me. But Thank you.

Comment: @Hein Because the website I'm trying to scraping coded like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I interpret that the third argument can not be changed or removed.
My proposal would be:

```py
for page in range(0, 27800, 20):
    print(f'page {(page/20)+1} =====')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is remove the third arguemnt u supplied to the `range` function as that paramter indicates the `step`, which is what the `start` paramter will be incremented by each iteration. The `step` paramter defaults to `1` which is the behaviour you are looking for.

```py
for page in range(0, 27800):
    print(f'page {page} =====')
```

For further reading on the `range` function and the parameters which it accepts: [range function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I need that 20 arguement (or parameter?). Because a website I'm trying to scrape was coded like that. So I need that 20, but I want to see print like 1, 2, 3.